# Simple string pattern matching

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

What's the easiest way of doing simple pattern matching a la *.something.com something.com/* something.com/somefolder/*.jpg in the iPhone SDK? At this point it looks like I'm going to have to use a regular expression library of some sort, which is really overkill when all I need is simple wildcard matching.
None of the standard NSString methods seem to be available on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the regular expression route: [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html) / [RegexKitLite-3.3.tar.bz2](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/regexkit/RegexKitLite-3.3.tar.bz2).  It's not an overkill, this is exactly the kind of problem that regular expressions are good at.

Answer (score 2):

For the equivalent of a matching expression with a single wildcard (*), you can use NSString's [hasPrefix:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasPrefix:) & [hasSuffix:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasSuffix:).

```
if ([string hasPrefix: @"something.com/somefolder/"] 
     && [string hasSuffix: @".jpg"])
{
   // string matches pattern: "something.com/somefolder/*.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Guess I should've specified an example with multiple wildcards as well. Additionally, this would be a real pain if the patterns used for matching aren't known up front, in which case one would need to first parse the pattern itself, so this isn't really the solution I was looking for.